# How do I interpret the results of the `ls -l` command?

Tags: unix, ls

I want to learn about the meaning of values for example first line;

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 ataka root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 ataka
```

is `ataka` here the owner of directory ?

```
kioutsovkm@orkide:/users/lnxsrv2/ee$ ls
ataka  aydinoglu  izgordu  kioutsovkm  kocaogluo
kioutsovkm@orkide:/users/lnxsrv2/ee$ ls -l
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 ataka     root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 ataka
drwxr-xr-x 2 aydinoglu root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 aydinoglu
drwxr-xr-x 3 izgordu   root 4096 2009-09-29 11:59 izgordu
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 kioutsovkm
drwxr-xr-x 4 kocaogluo root 4096 2010-06-10 03:41 kocaogluo
kioutsovkm@orkide:/users/lnxsrv2/ee$
```

Answer (score 52):

> Is ataka here the owner of directory?

Well, yes (third column), but it also happens to be the name of the directory (last column).

```
      +-permissions that apply to the owner
      |
      |     +-permissions that apply to all other users
      |     |
      |     |  +-number of hard links
      |     |  |
      |     |  |             +-size      +-last modification date and time
     _|_   _|_ |            _|__ ________|_______
    drwxr-xr-x 2 ataka root 4096 2008-11-04 16:58 ataka
        ___      _____ ____                       _____
         |         |    |                           |
         |         |    |                           +-name of file or directory
         |         |    |
         |         |    +-the group that the group permissions applies to
         |         |
         |         +-owner
         |
         +-permissions that apply to users who are members of the group
```

See [`man ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls), [`man chmod`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chmod) and [`info ls`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html) or `info coreutils 'ls invocation'` for more information.

Comment: What is the size of a directory?

Comment: @NickRetallack: [What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55/382)

Comment: How are hard links counted ?

Comment: @ychaouche: What do you mean? Whenever a hard link to a file is created or removed, the hard link count of that file is incremented or decremented.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `ataka` is an username and `root` is a group.